# Use ShutdownBlockRequestCreate in Win32 Console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7

**What is the proper method of blocking premature termination of a Win32 Console Application running on Windows 7?**

When Vista was introduced, there were changes regarding how [Application Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) happened.  Contrary to the behavior in XP, which was to open up a UI requesting whether the user wants to force close or not, Windows Vista (and 7) terminates the process if nothing is done programmatically to prevent it.  Console apps and applications without a top level window visible must also use the new function [ShutdownBlockRequestCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to provide a reason for Vista to show in the UI that pops up or it will terminate the program after 5 seconds anyway.

Below is my attempt at using the ShutdownBlockRequestCreate function in a Win32 Console application; the precompiled header option was removed from the project after creation by the wizard.  I get the error code of 5, corresponding to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, whenever I use the function.  This is apparently (according to the [Application Shutdown link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) because I am not calling the function from the same thread as was used to create the window (the console window).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *SBRCREATEFUNC)(HWND,LPCWSTR);

void RegisterShutdownBlockReason() {
    SBRCREATEFUNC ShutdownBlockReasonCreate;
    HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("user32.dll"));
    if (hinstLib != NULL) {
        ShutdownBlockReasonCreate = (SBRCREATEFUNC) GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"ShutdownBlockReasonCreate");
        if(ShutdownBlockReasonCreate != NULL) {
          if(!(ShutdownBlockReasonCreate) (hWnd, L"Terminating Communication Sessions")) {
              printf("\nfailed To Register Reason, failure code: %d\n", GetLastError());
          } else {
              printf("\nRegistered Reason\n");
          }
        } else {
            printf("\nCouldn't load ShutdownBlockReasonCreate procedure\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("\nFailed to LoadLibrary(\"user32.dll\")\n");
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    RegisterShutdownBlockReason();
    printf("Type to terminate program.\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, could you create a message-only window at startup and use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` on its window handle?

Comment: This is an enticing workaround.  I will investigate when I return to work.

Comment: This fit the bill for using the ShutdownBlockReasonCreate method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to pass the console window handle from a console program because the console window is owned by the CSRSS subsystem, not your console program. Furthermore, what if your console is run in full-screen text mode? Regardless of who owns what, now there's not even a window around your console!

Will it let you pass a `NULL` `hWnd`?

EDIT: Okay then, what if your console program creates its own hidden window and uses that?

Comment: Calling `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(NULL, "msg")` has a similar error code of ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  I think you touch upon the crux of the problem, though: that the console program is requested to provide a reason for blocking shutdown based on a HWND seems very suspect to me.  Whenever I run the exe (with a shortcut to, or by double clicking the icon) which spawns the console window, there *is* indeed a window with a title and buttons, which can be resized like any other window. If I were to run the exe from a command line, I'd be less willing to think of a window around the console, though.