# What is the best way to block system shutdown in an application

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm fairly new to the Windows API. I'm trying to figure out how to block system shutdown. I figured out about `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN`. Not exactly how to use it yet, but I was planning to do something along the following lines as [HandlerEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DWORD WINAPI serviceHandler(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    switch (dwControl)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:
        while (1)
            Sleep(1000);
    }
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

But A.) I'm not sure if I'm reading MSDN right, and implementing this `serviceHandler` correctly, and B.) Is there a better way of doing this. I essentially need this application to not allow shutdown unless it was forcibly by holding down the powerbutton.

Comment: Is this an application (e.g., run by double-clicking the exectuable or selecting an icon from the start menu) or a system service (e.g., run automatically when the system starts up or started via the Services administrative tool)?  At any rate, I think you want [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: What about using `system("shutdown /a");` to "abort" shutdown (if it can).

Comment: What if the shutdown was initiated by a UPS signalling imminent battery depletion? Just be aware that there is the potential for data loss from such an application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone provide an example of how to use windows ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190413/can-anyone-provide-an-example-of-how-to-use-windows-shutdownblockreasoncreate)

Answer (score 1):

You can't block system shutdown indefinitely like that. See the remarks for the `HandlerEx` callback function:

> The SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN control code should only be processed by
>   services that must absolutely clean up during shutdown, because there
>   is a limited time (about 20 seconds) available for service shutdown.
>   After this time expires, system shutdown proceeds regardless of
>   whether service shutdown is complete

After at most 20 seconds Windows will kill your service and continue the shutdown process.

Comment: Theoretically, ShutdownBlockReasonCreate should work, I think.  I've never tried using it.  Of course you have to call it before shutdown was initiated, not afterwards, and it isn't entirely clear to me whether it will work from a service or not.  (But then I'm not sure whether the OP is actually talking about a service.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm not sure it would work from a service since it needs a window handle.

Comment: It depends on what it uses that window handle for, which the documentation doesn't explain.  A service can create a window (it just isn't ever visible) so providing a window handle isn't an obstacle per se, but it does imply that the effect is somehow related to the current window station.  (Perhaps it just blocks Explorer's shutdown menus?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston The docs imply that the window handle is important ("the window must belong to the thread calling this function" etc). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615751/use-shutdownblockrequestcreate-in-win32-console-application) mentions that passing NULL for a window handle doesn't work either. So I would guess that it does matter, but yes this is all speculation.

Comment: "Because users are typically in a hurry when shutting down the system, they may spend only a few seconds looking at the shutdown reasons that are displayed by the system." I'm guessing the function throws up a modal dialog with your message. I'd have to test it.

Comment: Oh, according to [this](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx) it just affects [this screen](http://www.bartdesmet.net/images/shutdownblocking02.jpg), so it just uses the window handle for the window list there :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it from code, you should deploy several group policies, as described here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/128920-shut-down-computer-allow-prevent-users-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited time available for service shutdown.
20 seconds will help you block system shutdown.

The PC will perform an action similar to **"`shutdown -t 20 -s`"**, then quickly enter <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> \ **"`shutdown -a`"** and the above command will be canceled.

It can be easily implemented using `WinExec ()` or `CreateProcess ()`.

Comment: If the kernel has decided to shut down the system then there is *nothing* a user-space application can do to prevent that. It's going down.