# Can anyone provide an example of how to use windows ShutdownBlockReasonCreate

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Can anyone provide a simple clear example of `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`? I've been trying to figure it out through the MSDN pages but I'm not understanding it, and I'm getting really tired of having to turn off my computer every time I try and test it and it doesn't work. If someone is familiar and can provide a concise example that would be awesome!

This is what I have so far, but I do'

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(GetForegroundWindow(), s2ws("TEST").c_str()) != 0)
        std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Failure" << std::endl;

    while (1) 
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        std::cout << "Testing..." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific part of passing in a window handle and a textual message are you having difficulty with? The function takes exactly two parameters, both of which are basic types.

Comment: It's not hard to use, just give it a window and a string. The question is (as was discussed in the comments on your other question) whether it works from a service or not. This is far from clear, and if you're actually testing it you need to be checking whether the call fails and if so what error code is returned. If the call fails then clearly shutting down your machine to test it would be pointless.

Comment: If you scroll down in the documentation you should see this: `It's also important to return FALSE to the message WM_QUERYENDSESSION. Otherwise, Windows will never ask for shutdown reason.` which seems important.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble with the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and implementing that at all. I'm really new to the windows API. I've given it `GetForegroundWindow()` and a string, and it returns as success, but it doesn't work. I don't have WM_QUERYENDSESSION implemented and I'm confused how to do it. That's why I was hoping for an example. I don't need it as a service, just a stand alone program is what I want.

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far.  You can edit the code into your question.

Comment: Alright just put it at what I have as of right now.

Comment: From the documentation: "This function can only be called from the thread that created the window specified by the `hWnd` parameter." The thread that calls the function hasn't created any windows: the handle being returned by `GetForegroundWindow()` is thus necessarily created by some other thread. In other words, you can only use `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` on **your own** windows, not on somebody else's.

Comment: I just tried it with `GetActiveWindow()` but I'm not having luck with that either. It actually fails instead of succeeding.

Comment: I'm still having no luck on doing it with the console window for some reason.

Comment: @user1944429: you are ignoring what Igor told you.  **You cannot pass someone else's window** to `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`, you have to **create your own window**.  Use `CreateWindow/Ex()` for that.

Comment: @user1944429 I added a console example which is basically the same thing except the window is hidden and there's a little extra code to handle the console being closed and making sure the window gets destroyed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me in Windows 7.  You could also do it in a console program if you liked, this was a simpler example to write.  You should add error checking, I didn't to keep it short.

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInst;
HWND hWnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
            return FALSE;
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWnd, L"Don't do it!");
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hWnd);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TestClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    RECT sz = {0, 0, 512, 512};
    AdjustWindowRect(&sz, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, TRUE);
    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"TestClass", L"Test Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, sz.right - sz.left, sz.bottom - sz.top,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if(!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

A console version doesn't need to be drastically different, although you do need to create a window and run a message pump so I'm not sure what it buys you over a GUI app.  Obviously if you want to do work in either version you'll most likely end up needing a separate thread for the window or for your work.

Here's the simplest example of a console program I came up with.  You'll notice it's almost identical other than the ConsoleCtrlHandler to intercept the various ways of closing the console window and killing the GUI window instead.  It's also expected to be a MBCS project since I didn't want to change it in my test console project.

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInst;
HWND hWnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:
            return FALSE;
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_CREATE:
            ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hWnd, L"Don't do it!");
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hWnd);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "TestClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance;
    RECT sz = {0, 0, 512, 512};
    AdjustWindowRect(&sz, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, TRUE);
    hWnd = CreateWindow("TestClass", "Test Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, sz.right - sz.left, sz.bottom - sz.top,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleCtrlHandler(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    if(dwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT ||
        dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlHandler, TRUE);

    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if(!InitInstance(hInstance, SW_HIDE))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the console version work the same if the GUI window is hidden?

Comment: The GUI window is hidden in the console version.  It's only there to run a message loop to catch `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and provide a handle for `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

As you can probably guess by now, `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` does not actually block shutdown. All it does is tell Windows what message to say when it pops up [this screen](http://www.bartdesmet.net/images/shutdownblocking02.jpg).

To block shutdown on Windows, you need to have a window. This means that you will need to write a GUI program that uses a standard message pump. `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` is a message that is sent to all windows when the system wants to shut down. You can handle the message to block the shutdown request. But to understand this, you will need to understand Windows GUI programming. (You might not need an actual GUI; a message-only window *might* work. I don't know for sure.)

Your first question on the matter was about blocking shutdown from a system service. I am not an expert on Windows services so I don't know the answer to that. Services should not have GUIs due to running on session 0, however. I don't know if they can have message-only windows either.

Comment: I believe the OP never intended to ask about a system service, he simply didn't realize that the function he was trying to use only applied to system services.  Also, I don't think `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` can be used to block shutdown any more, at most it makes Windows wait a bit longer before prompting the user to kill the process.  (I may be misremembering.)

Comment: Perhaps; I'm not entirely sure what the person's end goal is :/ And right; that's what I assume that screen I linked is for =P I still don't know of any other way to inhibit or postpone shutdown, though.

Comment: Someone has posted an answer to the other question suggesting configuring group policy so that the (presumably non-administrative) user doesn't have any way to initiate shutdown. :-)   Bizarrely enough, that might actually be the only effective solution, depending, as you say, on the OPs end goal.

Comment: Re 'Services should not have GUIs' in more depth, its deliberately difficult, but there are some ways to do it. (And they are not recommended.) For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services